# Servo and Speaker Simultaneously

Tags: c++, arduino, servo, speaker

I am having trouble with moving my servo. I am using an IR sensor to play a song and I would like for the servo to move for a bit after pressing the button. I would also like for music to play after pressing the button. The music is playing but no matter where I put the servo_move function, the servo won't move after pressing the button. I am using the servotimer2 library to avoid timer errors.

```
#include <SD.h> // need to include the SD library
#include <TMRpcm.h> //Arduino library for asynchronous playback of 

#include <SPI.h> // need to include the SPI library
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 4 //connect pin 4 of arduino to cs pin of 

#define button1 0xFF30CF //Plays 34 + 35 
#define button2 0xFF18E7 //Plays Bad Day
#define button3 0xFF7A85 //Plays 3 Night 
int RECV_PIN = 2; //IR receiver pin

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
TMRpcm tmrpcm; // create an object for use in this sketch

//servo 
#include <ServoTimer2.h>  // the servo library uses another timer 
#define servoPin 3
ServoTimer2 myservo;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 myservo.attach(3);
 irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
 tmrpcm.speakerPin = 9; 
 if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) // returns 1 if the card is 

 {
 Serial.println("SD fail");
 return;
 }
}
void loop(){
 if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
 //Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
 irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
 if (results.value == button1)
 {
 Serial.println("Ariana Grande: 34 + 35");
 tmrpcm.play("3435.wav"); 
 } 
 if (results.value == button2)
 {
 Serial.println("Justus: Bad Day");
 tmrpcm.play("BadDay.wav"); 
 }
 if (results.value == button3)
 {
 Serial.println("Dominic Fyke: 3 Nights");
 tmrpcm.play("3Nights.wav"); 
 }
 } 
}
void servo_move(){ 
  myservo.write(750);  
  delay(20);
  myservo.write(1000);  
  delay(20);
  myservo.write(750);  
  delay(20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `servo_move()` inside the `void loop()` and put it inside the `if` statement. From what you were write inside the `if`, you only call the music-playing code and never call the moving-servo's.

maybe you can try this for your `void loop()` :

```
void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
  //Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
  irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
    if (results.value == button1)
    {
      Serial.println("Ariana Grande: 34 + 35");
      tmrpcm.play("3435.wav"); 
      servo_move();
    } 
    if (results.value == button2)
    {
      Serial.println("Justus: Bad Day");
      tmrpcm.play("BadDay.wav"); 
      servo_move();
    }
    if (results.value == button3)
    {
      Serial.println("Dominic Fyke: 3 Nights");
      tmrpcm.play("3Nights.wav");
      servo_move();
    }
  }

}

void servo_move(){ 
  myservo.write(750);  
  delay(20);
  myservo.write(1000);  
  delay(20);
  myservo.write(750);  
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: That did not work

Comment: you still include all the declaration and the void setup() right? What i was trying to say, just add the servo_move() to your desired "if" statement just like the "tmrpcm.play()".
I never use the library for playing music, but if calling the servo_move() does'nt work maybe you just need to wait untill the music stops with the servo_move() still called.
OR you can try to swab the line, servo_move() first and then tmrcpm.play()